# How to set properties if class has a static constructor?

Tags: properties, static, default-value, setter

I have a fully implemented property with private variable as shown below:

```
using System;

namespace ClaimMonitorInfo
{    
    internal class Claims
    {
        static Claims()
        {
            new MainModule();
        }

        private string claimName = string.Empty;
        public string ClaimName
        {
            get
            {
                return claimName ;
            }
            set
            {
                claimName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

External projects will be setting it but the property never gets set inside its own namespace. So Jenkins thought setter has never been used and gave me a warning message. The constructor of the class is static. How can I assign default values for the property? Need to mention that, project has to be built with MSBuild 12, so C# 6.0 features won't be acceptable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sincerely

Comment: Show us your class declaration and constructor. Why are the declarations not static?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: What is the intention of new MainModule();? The default of claimName would be string.Empty: use (new Claims()).ClaimName. A parameterless constructor is created by default.

Comment: Intention of MainModule is to initialize some common properties and execute methods. Here is comment from the code: Sets the current thread up for translation by establishing the correct UICulture.

Comment: I wanted to replace the fully-implemented property with auto-implemented one and set the property to string.Empty in the class or should I just skip the warning message in Jenkins?

Comment: Implement the non-static constructor and use this.ClaimName = string.Empty; inside; then you can use ClaimName { get; set; }

Comment: It seems issue was fixed and I missed your reply. Thanks for the answer.